# Defining new data type in ocaml

Tags: types, ocaml

Can anyone please explain me how we can define new data types in Ocaml and I am completely new to ocaml. Say , I have to define a new type bitseq, which is say all binary numbers.

So, what I did for it after going through various tutorials online was
type `num = Nil| 0 |1;;` and tried some variations of it which did not work out.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at the bit of the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual003.html#toc7) on variant types?

> Each case is identified by a name, called a constructor, which serves both for constructing values of the variant type and inspecting them by pattern-matching. **Constructor names are capitalized** to distinguish them from variable names (which must start with a lowercase letter).

Therefore you cannot use `0` or `1` as constructor names. If I were you and I didn't care about leading zeros in my representation of binary numbers, I'd go for the following:

```
type bit = Zero | One
type bitseq = bit list
```